# Parse update PFUser Class String

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, parse-platform

I am trying to update a specific users "totalScore" column in my Users class in parse. The "totalScore" is a string value. I am running the code below in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. I am getting `self.friends` from the queried list of users I want displayed in my tableview. When I run this code and log it, it seems to work fine but the object never updates in my data browser. Also: I am able to update this object online just not in app! Thanks!

```
 PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:user.objectId];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * userStats, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            [userStats setObject:@"#5" forKey:@"totalScore"];

            [userStats saveInBackground];


        } else {
            // Did not find any UserStats for the current user
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update any users information that's not you for security reasons. You have to be the currentUser to change your info.

Here is a workaround using cloud code :
https://parse.com/questions/users-editing-other-users-in-javascript-sdk

Comment: Okay thats what I figured. So is there a way around this?

Comment: You can simply use a separate table with user pointer -> score.